# На основе чего Math.random() в java генерирует числа?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Недавно начал изучать `Java`. Столкнулся с необходимостью генерации случайных чисел, пока писал код пришёл в голову вопрос "на основе чего `Math.random()` в java генерирует числа?". Я знаю, что пока не изобрели генератора истинно случайных чисел, и такие функции обычно генерируют число из каких-нибудь входных параметров (время с момента первого запуска компьютера, кэш, белый шум и т.д.). Так вот какую входную информацию использует `Java` для создания случайных чисел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого были придуманы `псевдослучайные числа`. Псевдослучайные числа — это некая последовательность, числа в которой на первый взгляд кажутся случайными, но специалист при детальном анализе сможет найти в них определенные закономерности. Для шифрования секретных документов такие числа не подойдут, а для имитации бросания кубика в игре — вполне.

Есть много алгоритмов генерации последовательности псевдослучайных чисел и почти все из них генерируют следующее случайное число на основе предыдущего и еще каких-то вспомогательных чисел.

Обычно их генерирует [ГПСЧ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) (Генератор Псевдослучайных Чисел). Он работает по алгоритмам и различным методам операций над числами. Наиболее распространены [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), [метод Фибоначчи с запаздываниями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8), [регистр сдвига с линейной обратной связью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E), [регистр сдвига с обобщённой обратной связью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E). Из современных ГПСЧ широкое распространение также получил «[вихрь Мерсенна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)».

`Math.random()` - это просто ярлык для вызова класса `Random`. Это более просто и менее полно, чем `java.util.Random`, но в некоторых случаях этого достаточно.

Класс `java.util.Random` реализует линейный конгруэнтный метод.